# How to make sure the div's never touch each others?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm building a battleship app. The goal is to randomly generate ships on the board every time the page refreshes. My problem is that I have to make sure that the ships never touch each other, I just can't figure it out.

Here's my ships array, each ship as a name and two directions :

```
const shipArray = [
        // sous marins x4
      
    {
      name: "destroyer",
      directions: [
        [0, 1],
        [0, width],
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "destroyer",
      directions: [
        [0, 1],
        [0, width],
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "destroyer",
      directions: [
        [0, 1],
        [0, width],
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "destroyer",
      directions: [
        [0, 1],
        [0, width],
      ],
    },

    //torpilleurs x3
    {
      name: "cruiser",
      directions: [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, width, width * 2],
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "cruiser",
      directions: [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, width, width * 2],
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "cruiser",
      directions: [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, width, width * 2],
      ],
    },
    //escorteurs x2
    {
      name: "battleship",
      directions: [
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, width, width * 2, width * 3],
      ],
    },

    {
      name: "battleship",
      directions: [
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, width, width * 2, width * 3],
      ],
    },
    //croiseur x1
    {
      name: "carrier",
      directions: [
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, width, width * 2, width * 3, width * 4],
      ],
    },
  ];
```

Here's the code than randomly generates ships on the board :

```
function generate(ship) {
    
    let randomDirection = Math.floor(Math.random() * ship.directions.length);
    let current = ship.directions[randomDirection];
    if (randomDirection === 0) direction = 1;
    if (randomDirection === 1) direction = 10;
    
    let randomStart = Math.abs(
      Math.floor(
        Math.random() * userSquares.length -
          ship.directions[0].length * direction
      )
    );

    

    const isTaken = current.some((index) =>
      userSquares[randomStart + index].classList.contains("taken")
    );

    const isAtRightEdge = current.some(
      (index) => (randomStart + index) % width === width - 1
    );

    const isAtLeftEdge = current.some(
      (index) => (randomStart + index) % width === 0
    );

    if (!isTaken && !isAtRightEdge && !isAtLeftEdge)
      current.forEach((index) =>
        userSquares[randomStart + index].classList.add("taken", ship.name)
      );
    else generate(ship);
}

  generate(shipArray[0]);
  generate(shipArray[1]);
  generate(shipArray[2]);
  generate(shipArray[3]);
  generate(shipArray[4]);
  generate(shipArray[5]);
  generate(shipArray[6]);
  generate(shipArray[7]);
  generate(shipArray[8]);
  generate(shipArray[9]);
```

[image]

Comment: If the task doesn't have other restrictions and trying to put a ship into some randomly chosen place is an appropriate approach, then you may imagine that every new ship has one square padding, and its dimensions would be 3 x (2 + ship_width) or (2 + ship_height) x 3. If the ship with the padding doesn't collide with others, then you may place it without the padding on the board.

Comment: See also [Battleship Probability Calculator](https://cliambrown.com/battleship/methodology.php) and [ManInTheBox/battleship](https://github.com/ManInTheBox/battleship/blob/7cb21df05dcfed839540e8198319a0c1ea735094/lib/battleship/grid.ex#L71)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to not generate a ship on a ship:

## The idea

I'll address the randomly generated ship `theShip` and any ship `aShip` (add a className to every ship maybe).
You can compare `theShip.offsetLeft` with the `elementFromPoint`. Create a function that does the following and add it to the function that creates new ships after the point it has created a ship.

- Set `theShip.style.pointerEvents = "none"`.
- Return and generate a new ship if any `aShip` is at `theShip`'s position.

  ```js
  if (document.elementFromPoint(theShip.offsetLeft, theShip.offsetTop)) {return}
  ```

You need to set `theShip.style.pointerEvents = "none"` so that `elementFromPoint` is not `theShip` itself.

## See:

- [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint)
- [offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft)
  from MDN.